# How to parse content of xml element including element tags

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

In an XML file, I am trying to parse the content of an element including the tags of other elements, so not just the text. I first tried to do it with regex, but read somewhere that this is not possible or very hard. Later I tried to use DOMParser, but have not been able to get it right. The XML file looks something like this:

```
<element1>
  <element2>
    ABC
  </element2>
  <element3>
    DEF
  </element3>
</element1>
```

My desired output is:

```
  <element2>
    ABC
  </element2>
  <element3>
    DEF
  </element3>
```

I am trying to do this in Javascript and my code now looks like this:

```
f = file.xml;
const content = fs.ReadFileSync(f, 'utf-8');
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc= new parser().parseFromString(content, "text/xml");
result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
return result;
```

I know that this would only return text in element1, and there is not any, but I don't know what the correct code would be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you both want to parse the XML and serialize some nodes back to a string you can use Saxon-JS and XPath 3.1 these days on both the client-side JavaScript platform as well as with Node.js:

```
var SaxonJS = require("saxon-js")

const content = `<element1>
  <element2>
    ABC
  </element2>
  <element3>
    DEF
  </element3>
</element1>`;

const xmlDoc = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('parse-xml($content)', [], { params : { content : content } });

var result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('serialize(/element1/node())', xmlDoc);

console.log(result);
```

```js
    const content = `<element1>
      <element2>
        ABC
      </element2>
      <element3>
        DEF
      </element3>
    </element1>`;
    
    const xmlDoc = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('parse-xml($content)', [], { params : { content : content } });
    
    var result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('serialize(/element1/node())', xmlDoc);
    
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```